# Why is my application returning no file names?

Tags: c#, console-application, system.io.file

I want my console app to return all folders and subdirectories but its not returning anything.

The temp folder is located in the correct place

```
using System.IO;

namespace Beginner_lessons
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)

        {
            var files = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\temp", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            foreach (var file in files)
                Console.WriteLine(file);

        }
    }
}
```

This is the code i get: C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe (process 16004) exited with code 0.

I'm expecting a list of all the folders in C:\temp

Comment: Are you checking files from Windows `Temp` directory? if so this is the actual path   ->  `C:\Windows\Temp` ?

Comment: `exited with code 0` means the program has finished without errors. Try to run the app without debugging or add additional `Console.ReadKey();` in the end.

Comment: Run using ctrl + f5 and it won't close

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you just need to keep the app open to read the result

```
...

foreach (var file in files)
   Console.WriteLine(file);

// hold the console open until a key is pressed
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm afraid that hasn't worked. When i run the application without debugging I get the same result and i get the same outcome with a console.readkey to. 

I have created the folder called temp myself yes.

Comment: @Richard well the code you have is sound (meaning it will get the files in the C:\Temp directory... there seems to be something odd here, i think you need to double all the facts